# How to disable Jenkins Pipeline stage view plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I got an issue with the Jenkins Pipeline stage view plugin:

### Issue

We have some job which makes use of loads of stages, that is roughly more than 500 stages.

Unfortunately that means that when opening the jobs main page the browser gets stuck. The only browser which so far managed to show me the jobs classic view main page was chrome. All others failed completely.

Therefore I'd like to find a way to disable the stage view completely. However looks like the Pipeline plugin depends on it.
I already tried to set `com.cloudbees.workflow.rest.external.JobExt.maxRunsPerJob=0` but that didn't work as hoped.
At least when setting `com.cloudbees.workflow.rest.external.JobExt.maxRunsPerJob=1` it'd only show the last run which is a small performance improvement.

### Question

Is there a way how to disable the stage view (plugin) in order to be able to see the main page for that insane job which unfortunately for now has to have that many (>500) stages?

Comment: Facing the same issue here. Browser is stuck until the stage view keeps loading.

Comment: you can disable the plugin directly on the installed plugins section of the plugin manager page without removing it -- but it will require a restart for changes to take effect. Or you might want to encapsulate your ton of stages as part a parent stage, this way when completed only the parent stage will be displayed in the UI.

Comment: Works :) Can you make this an answer so I can mark it as resolved?